# read csv and write in jSON file

Tags: json, scala, csv, apache-spark

l have a CSV file I need to parse it to a JSON file using Scala language how appear this error? I am using Spark version 3.3.5

I have this code

```
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator
import org.apache.log4j.varia.NullAppender
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}

object student {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val nullAppender = new NullAppender
BasicConfigurator.configure(nullAppender)

val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("Students data")
  .master("local")
  .getOrCreate

val studentDataFrame :DataFrame  = spark.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv("src/main/resources/students.csv")

val studentDataFrameJSON = studentDataFrame.toJSON

studentDataFrameJSON.write
  .format("json")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .save("src/main/resources/studentsJSON.json")

val jsonDF: DataFrame = spark.read.json("src/main/resources/studentsJSON.json")
jsonDF.show()
  }
```

appear this error

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1249)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1454)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:377)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$writeAndCommit$3(FileFormatWriter.scala:275)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:552)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.writeAndCommit(FileFormatWriter.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeWrite(FileFormatWriter.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(origin.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:437)
    at 
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:98)
    at 
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at 
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:859)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:240)
    at student$.main(student.scala:26)
    at student.main(student.scala)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates a `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`, which usually occurs when you're running an application
that depends on native libraries and those libraries are either not available, not accessible, or not compatible. Specifically, the error suggests that a native method in the Hadoop `NativeIO` library is not found,
and it typically appears when running Spark on a Windows system.

Steps to Resolve the Error:

- Use `winutils` : If you're running on Windows, one commonly recommended workaround is to download a winutils.exe binary compatible with your Hadoop version and place it in a directory. You can find about winutils [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68381151/how-winutils-acts-like-hadoop-what-does-it-do-excatly) and download it [here](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils)
- Then set the `hadoop.home.dir` system property to point to that directory.
  Here's how you can do it in your code: `System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir","path_to_your_hadoop_home_directory")`
- Also check library paths: Ensure that the native libraries required by Hadoop are in the `java.library.path`.

You can print java.library.path to find where it is:
`println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"))`